# Unable to set nav drawer to something that is not the rootview controller

Tags: ios, swift, navigation-drawer, cosmicmind

Is there a way to set the the navigation drawer without making the the view controller the root view controller as set in the example [here](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Material/Programmatic/NavigationDrawerController/NavigationDrawerController) in the app delegate file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set the `NavigationDrawerController` to the `UIWindow.rootViewController`. That is done to ensure that the drawer actually covers everything. At the moment, there isn't an independent NavigationDrawer, but you could set the NavigationDrawerController as a child UIViewController of another view controller.